# Where is Chrome Extension's Setting Files/Databases?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extensions

I don't seem to find Chrome Extension's Setting Files/Databases in OSX, it is not in the extension folder aka `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions` is for the static extension files only. Storage space for Extensions is found in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage`:

```
IanCsiMac:~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage |ruby-2.1.2|
> ls | grep redditenhancement
http_redditenhancementsuite.com_0.localstorage
http_redditenhancementsuite.com_0.localstorage-journal
```

Comment: You are the man!